# Getting the number of failed login attempts since the last successful login

Tags: centos, ssh, ansible

How can I reproduce this message, when we make an SSH connection:

Last failed login: Sun Feb 19 03:52:25
**There were 41 failed login attempts since the last successful login.**

I want to configure a playbook in Ansible, that will make this check in a group of hosts. Is that possible? Which service is responsible to generate this message?

If not, can someone point me a good way out to reach this? I know I can get failed attempts from secure log, but don't know exactly how calculate the number after the last successful access.

Comment: CentOS 7 server.

Comment: Welcome to U&L! Please, could you elaborate your answer? You can go to the help center for guidance on how to do so. For now, please edit your answer if you have details to add instead of putting them into comments.

Comment: @Paradox Elaborate the question, there is a typo there.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro My bad, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: The following answer assumes that you do not connect to your server via SSH, but that it is accessed only via Ansible

---

Probably not the most elegant solution, but hopefully good enough:

```
- name: Failed logins since last playbook execution
  shell: 'echo $((`lastb | wc -l` - 2)) ; > /var/log/btmp'
```

Explanation (sorry if I'm being Cpt. Obvious here...):

- `lastb` is a command listing unsuccessful logins, its output is based on the contents of `/var/log/btmp`
- `` is one way how to do command substitution, whose aim is to replace a command with its output, so that it could become an argument for yet  another command - in this case, the double parentheses for arithmetic operations, i.e. `$(()))`
- `lastb | wc -l` returns the line count of `/var/log/btmp`, however, we need to substract 2 from that to get our desired result, because the second last line of `/var/log/btmp` is an empty line, and the last line contains a timestamp, e.g.

  ```
  btmp begins Sat Feb 19 18:50:43 2022
  ```
- Finally, in order to reset the failed login count, we truncate `/var/log/btmp`